# Angular Working with object: Fix it

Tags: java, angularjs, thymeleaf

I need some advise. I have an UI that is working under spring. And I want to sent and object to the UI to load some information and sent back to the controller. So far I made the part that I receive all in the UI. But now I have the problem that I can't work with it. Could you help me plz?

Controller is:

```
 public String showPage(ModelMap model) {
    AnalysisModel requestView = new AnalysisModel();
    requestView.setAnalysisId(3);
    model.addAttribute("REQUEST_VIEW", new Gson().toJson(requestView));
    return "BLAH";
}
```

In my page I do this: `<div ng-controller="you" th:attr="ng-init='init(\''+ ${requestview}+'\')'">`
And in angular I have this:

```
$scope.init = function(requestview){
    //$scope.requestView = requestview
    //for fix the code you just need to encoding the object like this
    $scope.requestView = angular.fromJson(requestview);                         
};
```

The problem is that if i put in the UI something like `{{requestView}}` I can see the full object but if i put `{{requestView.AnalysisId}}` I dont have any answer. 
What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks friends!

Comment: You are not encoding object when you pass it to the `init`, you are passing just a string.

Comment: Thanks @dfsq !!! I get it working :)